# Why can't I include Kernel in the singleton class of an instance of Object

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In the top-level :

```
unbinded_method = method :puts

#=> Object(Kernel)#puts(*arg1)
```

but I did this

```
obj = Object.new

obj.puts 'wow'
```

I got an undefined error

so I assumed the Kernel module didn't include in the singleton class of obj, so I did

```
obj.instance_eval do

include Kernel

end
```

but I got error again:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `include' for #<Object:0x00000100b14dc8>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why can't I include Kernel in the singleton class of an instance of Object

Uhm, you *can*:

```
obj = Object.new
obj.singleton_class.ancestors
# => [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

class << obj
  include Kernel
end
obj.singleton_class.ancestors
# => [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Note: obviously, `include`ing `Kernel` into an instance of `Object` doesn't actually *do* anything, because `Kernel` is *already* in the ancestor chain, and mixins can only appear once in the ancestor chain. But if you `include` *another* mixin, that will work:

```
obj = Object.new
obj.singleton_class.ancestors
# => [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

class << obj
  include Enumerable
end
obj.singleton_class.ancestors
# => [Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

> but I did this
>
> ```
> obj = Object.new
>
> obj.puts 'wow'
> ```
>
> I got an undefined error

No, you didn't. This is the error you got:

```
# NoMethodError: private method `puts' called for #<Object:0xdeadbed>
```

It tells you *right there* in the error what the problem is: `Kernel#puts` is private, and in Ruby, private methods can only be invoked as the result of a receiverless message send. For example like this:

```
obj.instance_eval do puts 'wow' end
# wow
```

or just

```
obj.send :puts, 'wow' # send cirvumvents access protection
# wow
```

> so I assumed the Kernel module didn't include in the singleton class of obj [...]

Why did you assume instead of just check?

```
obj.singleton_class.ancestors.include? Kernel # => true
```

> so I did
>
> ```
> obj.instance_eval do
>   include Kernel
> end
> ```
>
> but I got error again:
>
> NoMethodError: undefined method `include' for #

Again, the error message already tells you everything you need to know: `Object` doesn't have an `include` method, nor is there one in its ancestor chain. `include` is a method of the `Module` class, but `obj` is an `Object`, not a `Module`.

Comment: your explanation about private method is the best, totally make sense to me, thanks for your great answer of all time!

Comment: @jorg Could you look into my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419429/confusion-with-singleton-method-defined-on-class-object/15445800?noredirect=1#15445800) please?