# Confusion with singleton method defined on `Class` object

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

What I know singleton methods can be called by the objects, on which it is defined. Now in the below example `C` is also an object of `Class` and singleton method `a_class_method` defined on the `Class` object `C`. So how does another `Class` object `D` able
to call `a_class_method`?

> *How does object `individuation` principle holds in this example?*

```
class C
end
#=> nil

def C.a_class_method
 puts "Singleton method defined on #{self}"
end
#=> nil

C.a_class_method
#Singleton method defined on C
#=> nil

class D < C
end
#=> nil

D.a_class_method
#Singleton method defined on D
#=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

well when you did the < you made class D inherit from Class C so D will get anything from class C.  If you want to know what all D's parents are you can do

```
puts "D's parent Classes = #{D.ancestors.join(',')}"
```

which will give you

```
D's parent Classes = D,C,Object,Kernel
```

So even though D would be an individual class it is a sub class of C which is what lets it use a method defined for C

Comment: My point was regarding the `individuation` . What you said is correct interns of `inheritance`. Which is understood. But we generally called `singleton` methods by the object with which we have created. Now here it is the singleton method created on the Class object `C`, But we are getting access to that method via the class object `D` too. -- This is the confusion I am having.

Comment: Ok, I did not even know you could do that, i though singleton methods where only really for objects not for classes.  Hopefully someone with a better grasp of this will chime in.

Comment: May I have some vote for this, which might increase this post's interest? :)

Comment: just opened up the account yesterday so I cannot up vote yet :/ need 2 more reputation apparently

Comment: K thanks, I am curious to hear what response you get.  I did some searches because I was curious and all the singleton stuff I found had to do with defining something on an object not on a class ex:


    `objectC=C.new`
    `def objectC.singleton_method`
           `something`
    `end`

    D.singleton_method will not exist then and neither will C.singleton_method because that was defined only for the singleton class for the objectC

Comment: Humm you can taken a look another post of [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451396/where-does-singleton-methods-reside-in-ruby?noredirect=1#comment21861842_15451396). Hope you would enjoy it.

Comment: I see you understand that by your other post :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `a_class_method` is available is that:

```
D.singleton_class.superclass == C.singleton_class
 # => true
```

Comment: here is another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453509/confusion-with-instance-variables-object-id-allocation-in-ruby) - hope you will enjoy it. :)