# Where does `singleton` methods reside in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3, singleton-methods

I was playing with `singleton class` in my IRB. And doing so tried the below snippets.

```
class Foo ; end
#=> nil
foo = Foo.new
#=> #<Foo:0x2022738>

foo.define_singleton_method(:bar , method(:puts))
#=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#puts>
```

Here above I just created a `singleton` method on instance of class `Foo`.

```
foo.bar("hi")
hi
#=> nil
foo.singleton_methods
#=> [:bar]

foo_sing = foo.singleton_class
#=> #<Class:#<Foo:0x2022738
foo_sing.is_a? Class
#=> true
foo_sing.instance_of? Class
#=> true
foo_sing.inspect
#=> "#<Class:#<Foo:0x1e06dc8>>"
```

In the above I tried to create a `singleton class` on instance of class `Foo`. And also tested if  `foo_sing` holds reference to the `singleton class` on instance of class `Foo`.

```
foo_sing.methods(false)
#=> []
foo_sing.methods.include? :bar
#=> false
```

In the above I was looking if `singleton_method` `bar` is in the `foo_sing` or not.But found it is not present there.Then my question is - ***where does those`singleton_method` reside in Ruby?***

```
foo_sing.new.methods(false)
#TypeError: can't create instance of singleton class
#        from (irb):10:in `new'
#        from (irb):10
#        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
class Bas < foo_sing ; end
#TypeError: can't make subclass of singleton class
#        from (irb):16
#        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

In the above part I was checking if we can create,instance of `singleton class` or not and subclass of `singleton class`,like regular class. But the answers I found as NO. ***What is the concept or theory or purpose behind it ?***

Again in the following code I can see the that same name methods are being overridden inside a `singleton class`. But when I am searching that method inside the class not found as I asked above.

```
class Foo ; end
#=> nil
foo = Foo.new
#=> #<Foo:0x225e3a0>

def foo.show ; puts "hi" ; end
#=> nil

foo.show
#hi
#=> nil

class << foo ;def show ; puts "hello" ; end ;end
#=> nil

foo.show
#hello
#=> nil
```

Comment: Why is it important where they live? Isn't it a lot more important that they work? If it's really important to you, look in the source code.

Comment: I think @iAmRubuuu wants to gain understanding about singleton classes.

Comment: BTW, I will post a blog post in a few days and will try to answer these.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune yes, you are right. Thanks to understand my curiosity.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune Woww, Nice to hear from you that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.

1) When looking for the method in the singleton class, you wanted to use `instance_methods`, not `methods`:

```
foo_sing.instance_methods.include? :bar # => true
# or
foo_sing.method_defined? :bar # => true
```

It is a bit confusing, since `method_defined?` really means "instance methods defined?", while  `methods` really means `singleton methods`...

2) You can't subclass or instantiate a singleton class because it is meant to be a singleton, i.e. have exactly one instance.

It doesn't matter anyways, since you should instead use mixins for code that you want to reuse. These can be included/prepended in as many singleton classes or normal classes as you want:

```
foo.extend ResuableFunctionality
# or equivalently:
class << foo
  include ReusableFunctionality
end
```

Comment: Sure I will. I wanna to see all the answers or more on that. If you write it on your post,it would be great. :)