# Confusion with instance variables object id allocation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I was trying to understand the instance variable initialization and declaration. Doing so I tried the below code. But in the half of my thinking path,I got something interesting as below:

```
class Person
attr_accessor :name,:age
    def initialize(var)
     @sex = var
    end
    def objctid
        p ":age -> #{@age.object_id}"
        p ":name -> #{@name.object_id}"
        p ":sex -> #{@sex.object_id}"
    end
end
#=> nil

ram = Person.new('M')
#=> #<Person:0x2109f48 @sex="M">

ram.objctid
#":age -> 4"
#":name -> 4"
#":sex -> 17321904"
#=> ":sex -> 17321904"
```

I didn't use `Object#instance_variable_set` till now.

***How does the symbols `:age` and `:name` get the memory references,as I didn't intialize them till above?***

***Why does the `object_id` of those instance variables are same ?***

```
ram.instance_variable_set(:@age,'14')
#=> "14"
```

Now in the below code `@age` s object_id changed as I used `Object#instance_variable_set` to set `@age`.

```
ram.objctid
#":age -> 17884656"
#":name -> 4"
#":sex -> 17321904"
#=> ":sex -> 17321904"

ram.instance_variable_set(:@name,'Lalu')
#=> "Lalu"

ram.objctid
#":age -> 16884288"
#":name -> 17041356"
#":sex -> 17625228"
#=> ":sex -> 17625228"
```

*** Why such different object_id of `@age` and `@name`? ***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance variables are created and initialized to `nil` when they're first referenced. For example:

```
class C
    def m
        puts @unset.inspect
    end
end
C.new.m
```

will say `nil`.

You don't initialize `@age` or `@name` so they're created and initialized to `nil` when you first reference them inside your `objctid` method. Since they're both `nil`, they will have the same `object_id` since there is only one `nil`; adding `p nil.object_id` to your `objctid` method might be fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

**How does the symbols :age and :name get the memory references ?**

as you haven't assigned them any value so by default they get a  `nil` object

**Why does the object_id of those instance variables are same ?**

because there is only one `nil`